# Quote about windows

Tags: meaning, quotes

I'm not sure if this is where I should be asking this.. But it seemed to be the most appropriate community on StackExchange.

Anyways, I'm setting up a Google+ page for a small business that does window cleaning. As a first post, I want to post a nice photo of a window that they sent me, and accompany it with a nice quote that has to do with windows. This is one I found:

> “Set wide the window. Let me drink the day.”

It's a quote from [a work by Edith Wharton](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Edith_Wharton).

Now, I take it to mean, very simply, that someone wants to open their window wide and enjoy the view.

My question: Is that the meaning of the quote? Does it mean anything deeper? Mostly I just don't want to embarrass myself by posting that and then realizing it has some totally different meaning.

Comment: You probably have the right meaning but, when I first read it, I saw "drink the day" as implying that you would be drinking beer, wine, etc for the rest of the day. You have to careful with quotes, especially obscure ones.

Comment: This asks about deeper interpretation, veiled meanings, creative metaphors, and is a better fit on Literature.SE.

Comment: Not good for your context.

Comment: I'm confused -- is the window open or closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it right. It means what it sounds like.

Answer (score 0):

Someone wants or needs to come closer to the window and get a better view rather than staring from a distance. Also, by coming closer you may be able to hear and smell parts of the day coming through the window.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I took it as a metaphorical meaning. The window would be symbolic of opening oneself or one's heart up. To "set wide" would be to open yourself fully to the possibilities of life. 'Drinking in the day' to me means taking in all parts that the day should offer, or rather, life itself might offer to those open to the experience. That to open oneself up to take in, essentially renders one vulnerable. So you are going to savor experiences, positive or negative, boring or prolific, etc. Much like you could choose to open wide a literal window on a sunny morning, but less likely to open it on a cold and windy one, perhaps the idea of setting the window wide is to open oneself up, no matter the conditions of the external world. And to experience it all with the same curiosity and wonderment.